# Why is setting a String in class not possible but getting the String possible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, getter-setter

My problem includes an `Activity` and a `RecyclerViewAdapter`.
I want to pass the Stringvalue of an Uri from my `Activity` to my `RecyclerViewAdapter`.
For passing I am using this *Getter and Setter* class:

#### updateDataAdapter.java

```
public class updateDataAdapter {

    public String testurl;

    public String getTesturl() {
        return testurl;
    }

    public void setTesturl(String testurl) {
        this.testurl = testurl;
    }
}
```

The Recyclerview sends an intent with `((Activity) context).startActivityForResult();` and the Activity uses `onActivityResult`  to receive the `intent` and RequestCode.

Code from `Recyclerview .java`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setType("image/*");

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);
```

The `Context` is the `Activity` (Given as parameter at Setting the adapter).

Code of `onActivityResult` in `Activty`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {

    super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);

    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri2 = I.getData();

        updateDataAdapter  updateDataAdapter = new updateDataAdapter();

        try { 
            updateDataAdapter.setTesturl(String.ValueOf(uri2));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem:

If I call `getTesturl` in my `RecyclerViewAdapter` the String is empty.

That's why I tried different things to locate the problem.

First I set  (in my `updateDataAdapter.java`) `public String testurl;` to `public String testurl = "This is my text";` and calling `getTesturl` receives the text *"This is my text"*.

#### So I could conclude that the problem is `setTesturl`.

So I tried to replace `updateDataAdapter.setTesturl(String.ValueOf(uri2));`  with `updateDataAdapter.setTesturl("This is my text");`

But in this case the String is empty.

How can I solve the problem and why is my code not working?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'updateDataAdapter' should declared class member variable.

```
private updateDataAdapter  updateDataAdapter = new updateDataAdapter();

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {

    super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);


    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri2 = I.getData();

        try { 
            updateDataAdapter.setTesturl(String.ValueOf(uri2));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
       }}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

    Uri uri2 = I.getData();

    updateDataAdapter  updateDataAdapter = new updateDataAdapter();

    try { 
        updateDataAdapter.setTesturl(String.ValueOf(uri2));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }}
  }
```

Here you create a new `updateDataAdapter`. Replace the newly created  `updateDataAdapter` with the existing `RecyclerViewAdapter`.